# Does SLComposeViewController permit setting the location field?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

When presenting an `SLComposeViewController` in an iOS 7 app, the location field always defaults to "none", even when the associated Twitter and/or Facebook accounts have location privacy settings that permit display of their current location.

Is this the expected behavior of SLComposeViewController?  Is there a public API for triggering a location lookup, or for setting the location directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not set the location manually. A user must set it explicitly.

[Looking at the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is no mention of 'location'.

Comment: OK, that's the answer I expected at this point.  I guess that means that I need to build a custom tweet sheet.